# Avoid regex balancing group to move out of parentheses

Tags: .net, regex, balancing-groups

I'm using the following regex to match the contents of any datascript script referencing a specific UDF:

```
\[?shared3\]?\.\[?stringsum\]?(((?'Open'\()[^()]*)+((?'Close-Open'\))[^()]*)+)*
```

it matches any instance of:

```
Shared3.StringSum(<some contents here>)
```

Using the balancing groups, I'm trying to also support cases like:

```
Shared3.StringSum(SomeOtherMethod('input') + AnotherMethod('input'))
```

However, I'm running into trouble, when the input is like:

```
Shared3.StringSum(SomeOtherMethod('input') + AnotherMethod('input')) + ThirdMethod('input')
```

In the last case, my regex also matches the `ThirdMethod('input')` part.

Is there any way I can alter my regex, so it stops matching as soon as the "parentheses count" is 0?

Comment: Try `\[?shared3]?\.\[?stringsum]?\(((?>[^()]+|(?'Open'\()|(?'Close-Open'\)))*)\)`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%3fshared3%5d%3f%5c.%5c%5b%3fstringsum%5d%3f%5c%28%28%28%3f%3e%5b%5e%28%29%5d%2b%7c%28%3f%27Open%27%5c%28%29%7c%28%3f%27Close-Open%27%5c%29%29%29*%29%5c%29&i=Shared3.StringSum%28SomeOtherMethod%28%27input1%27%29+%2b+AnotherMethod%28%27input2%27%29%29%0d%0aShared3.StringSum%28SomeOtherMethod%28%27input1%27%29+%2b+AnotherMethod%28%27input2%27%29%29+%2b+ThirdMethod%28%27input%27%29&o=i).

Comment: Great, this fixes the issue. It isn't the exact regex I need, because of some other issues, but I was able to solve them.

Comment: What other issues? If it fixes the current issue it is a valid solution. Please edit the question if you want me to adjust it.

Comment: These other issues are unrelated to the question scope, so your answer is correct. No reason to panic :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
\[?shared3]?\.\[?stringsum]?\(((?>[^()]+|(?'Open'\()|(?'Close-Open'\)))*)\)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%3Fshared3%5D%3F%5C.%5C%5B%3Fstringsum%5D%3F%5C%28%28%28%3F%3E%5B%5E%28%29%5D%2B%7C%28%3F%27Open%27%5C%28%29%7C%28%3F%27Close-Open%27%5C%29%29%29%2A%29%5C%29&i=Shared3.StringSum%28SomeOtherMethod%28%27input1%27%29%20%2B%20AnotherMethod%28%27input2%27%29%29%0D%0AShared3.StringSum%28SomeOtherMethod%28%27input1%27%29%20%2B%20AnotherMethod%28%27input2%27%29%29%20%2B%20ThirdMethod%28%27input%27%29&o=i)

**Details**

- `\[?shared3]?` - an optional `[`, `shared`, and an optional `]`
- `\.` - a dot
- `\[?stringsum]?  - an optional`[`,`stringsum`, and an optional`]`
- `\(` - a `(`
- `((?>[^()]+|(?'Open'\()|(?'Close-Open'\)))*)` - Group 1: one or more occurrences of

  - `[^()]+|` - 1+ chars other than `(` and `)`, or
  - `(?'Open'\()|` - Group "Open": pushes `(` into group stack
  - `(?'Close-Open'\))` - Group "Close" and "Open": pops the `)` from the `Open` group stack and saves the current level substring into `Close` group
- `\)` - a `)` char to finish things up